# running a simple query of sql server in c#

Tags: c#, sql

I am trying to run a test query using sql. I know it is a simple concept, but i have tried everything I could find online and the following does not even run. It shows no errors but it does not run.

```
private static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>");

public static void connect()
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spTester 'this is tested'", conn);
    command.ExecuteScalar();
    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: you are doing it wrong buddy

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: spTester is a stored procedure that inserts a column into a table named tester. I checked this table it seems to be empty. However when I run "spTester 'this is tested'" as it is in the db, it inserts a row

Comment: Why do you use ExecuteScalar() instead of ExecuteNoQuery()?

Comment: what does ExecuteNoQuery() do? how are they different?

Comment: @Neville Nazerane: ExecuteNoQuery() doesn't return any result value; ExecuteScalar returns single value result; ExecuteReader() returns a cursor of result records.

Comment: it throws an error "does not contain a definition for 'ExecuteNoQuery' and no extension method 'ExecuteNoQuery' "

Comment: @Neville Nazerane: I'm very sorry for the typo: "ExecuteNonQuery()"

Comment: @DmitryBychenko, Could you write that as an answer so i can mark it as the right answer. I managed to resolve the issue and my resolution would annoy everyone. However your answer is closest to the solution. The others are not even the right way.

Answer (score 6):

It seems that you want something like that:

```
private static void connect() {
  // static SqlConnection conn is a bad idea, local variable is much better
  // Do not forget to dispose IDisposable: using(...) {...}
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("<connection string>")) {
    // Do not forget to dispose IDisposable: using(...) {...}
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spTester", conn)) {
      // You're executing procedure, not ordinal SQL
      command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
      // It seems, that you should provide a parameter to your procedure:
      //TODO: Change "@ParameterName" to actual one
      command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ParameterName", "this is tested"));

      // You don't need any result value be returned
      command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: tried and still no output. I guessed there is something wrong with my connection string although it doesnt throw an error.

Comment: StoredProcedure does not work since it has a variable as well and is run as an sql

Comment: If the "spTester" has a parameter (which is "this is tested") you should explictly declare it either with StoredProcedure or Text command type. See my edit. Do not forget to change @ParameterName to the real parameter name

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void connect()
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spTester 'this is tested'", conn);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    conn.Close();
}
```

try doing this.. 
as u probably forgot to mention `command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;` line

Comment: CommandType throws a but as not defined. Do I have to include something using 'using'?

Comment: Put tht inside try catch @NevilleNazerane

Comment: i just realized whatever connection string i use it throws no error. Is there a way to test the connection strin gin the first place?

Comment: Have u taken name space `using System.Data.SqlClient;`?

Comment: this is my declaration using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

Comment: my connection string is set in this format

`private static SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=<server>;Database=<database>;User ID=<user>;Password=<pass>");`

This connection string was used in other websites (not in SqlConnection) and works perfectly

Comment: @NevilleNazerane then wher u are getting exception or error?

Comment: StoredProcedure does not work since it has a variable as well and is run as an sql

Comment: @NevilleNazerane u cn pass the parameter using `Get` and `set` method

Comment: i did not have to. i figured out the issue. it had nothing to do with CommandType

Answer (score 0):

this is a simple example it will let you get started using `SQLCOMMAND`

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM whatever 
                                   WHERE id = 5", conn);
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        newID = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :

public static void connect()
{
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("spTester", conn);
    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    command.AddWithValue("@Parameter1","this is tested")
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    conn.Close();
}
```